# struts2 jQuery grid Dialog popup on double click grid with values populated from an action

Tags: jquery, struts2-jquery

I have a `struts2-Jquery` grid. It is required that on double clicking a grid row
the grid row key should be caputerd and a struts2 action(returning json) to be called which fetches details from database corresponding to key and shows result in jquery dialog.
I implemented in following way but the dialog was not populating because the mapping is not correct .

I then used session to store and read at jsp but it shows same value every time

I need a help to find out how to know

```
$("#detailDialog").load("<s:url value="my-dialogAction"/>"+"?gridKey="+key);     
should returns success and only then to publish   
$.publish('loadSuccessConfirm');
```

Code snippets

---------Jquery grid code ---------

```
< sjg:grid id="mytable" ..   
.. ..  
onDblClickRowTopics="popup"  
>  

< sjg:gridColumn .. />   
< sjg:gridColumn .. /> ..
```

-------------java script---

```
< script type="text/javascript" >  
$.subscribe('popup', function(event, data) {  
    var key = $("#mytable").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');  
    $("#detailDialog").load("<s:url value="my-dialogAction"/>"+"?gridKey="+key);  
    $.publish('loadSuccessConfirm');  

});  

< /script>
```

----------------dialog------------

```
< sj:div id="detailDialog" name="detailDialog" >  
< sj:dialog position="center" height="200" width="500" openTopics="loadSuccessConfirm"   name="dialog1"  id="dialog1" autoOpen="false"  >  

    < s:iterator value="#session.comparePorts" status="stat" var="stack">  
        < tr>  
        < td><s:property value="#stack.airPortFrom"/> </td>  
        < td><s:property value="#stack.transportMode"/></td>  
        < td><s:property value="#stack.svc"/></td>    
        < td><s:property value="#stack.calcCostLoad"/></td>  

        < /tr>  
        <  /s:iterator>  

< /sj:dialog>   

< /sj:div>
```

---

Update

I edited script code as below and it publishes after success but still dialog shows stale value and is not getting refreshed

```
$.subscribe('popup', function(event, data) {
    var key = $("#mepctable").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    $("#detailDialog").load("<s:url value="my-dialogAction"/>"+"?gridKey="+key,
        function() { alert("success");$.publish('loadSuccessConfirm');});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<s:property />` tag is evaluated at page render time and it would not be changed.

May be you should put the dialog content as another jsp/action and use ajax to call that page using the `href` attribute of `<sj:dialog />`. And to use `listenTopics` to make the dialog reload when there's a double click on the row.

https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DialogTag